# Слова образованные от основ

Tags: грамматика

Основа слова не включает в себя окончание. У меня в учебнике написано: Слово нищенский образовано от основы *нищий* (если просклонять: *нищему*). Т. е., *-ий* — окончание.

Получается, что *нищий* — это не основа?

Comment: _Никита: Получается, что **нищий** - это не основа?_ === Конечно, не основа. Основа плюс окончание: _**нищ**_ + _**ий**_.

Comment: Суфикс инск пишется в именах прилагательных, образованых от основ, оканчивающихся на ИН, а также И(Ы), А(Я) Нищенский от нищий. Непонятно. Спорить с автором не хочется, написано именно от основ.

Comment: Если в учебнике написано именно так, как Вы говорите, то это недоработка авторов учебника. Правильнее было бы написать _"...от основы **слова** НИЩИЙ"._  А суффикс в слове _нищенский_ -- _**енск**_: нищ+енск+ий. Такой же, как в словах _кладбищенский, рождественский..._

Comment: Скорее всего, в учебнике так и написано: "...от основы слова НИЩИЙ".Просто Никита не понял. Это какой автор и какой класс?

Comment: @Людмила это Драбкина, по подготовке к ЕГЭ за 2017 год. Не в первый раз дописываю карандашом в учебник...

Comment: И там выделено в слове нищИЙ (две последние буквы), а не нищИй. И сами правила во многих моментах не понятны, например такая запись: Оканчивается на -А(Я) - имеется введу (АЯ или А) / (А или Я) - везде по разному, а структура записи одна. Хочу сменить учебник... на что-то более качественное, но не знаю пока на что.

Comment: Например еще один ее пример: Мытищинский (от мытищИ). Если в нем так много ошибок, почему его каждый год переиздают и продают?!

Comment: Как вам такой ресурс: http://russkiy-na-5.ru/sections/216?

Comment: http://russkiy-na-5.ru/articles/987 Ага, у нее второе правило не верное...

Answer (score 1):

Никита,во-первых, это не учебник, а пособие для подготовки к ЕГЭ.

Во-вторых, правило "Суффикс -инск пишется в именах прилагательных, образованных от основ, оканчивающихся на ИН, а также И(Ы), А(Я)" верное, но укороченное. Должно быть так:

1. Прилагательные оканчиваются на -инский:

а) если от соответствующих существительных употребительно притяжательное прилагательное на -ин, например: се'стринский (сестра - сестрин), Мари'инский (Мария - Мариин), А'ннинский (Анна - Аннин), Са'ввинский (Савва - Саввин);

б) если они образованы от географических названий (склоняемых и несклоняемых), оканчивающихся на -и (-ы), например: гря'зинский (Грязи), мыти'щинский (Мытищи), хи'мкинский (Химки), со'чинский (Сочи), то'пкинский (Топки), та'лсинский (Талсы);

в) если они образованы от географических названий, оканчивающихся на -а (-я), например: жи'здринский (Жиздра), я'лтинский (Ялта), о'хтинский (Охта), балаши'хинский (Балашиха), е'льнинский (Ельня).

Примечание. Некоторые прилагательные, образованные от существительных на -а (-я), в соответствии с прочно установившейся традицией сохраняют написание с -енский, например: пре'сненский (Пресня), пе'нзенский (Пенза).

2. Прилагательные оканчиваются на -енский, если они принадлежат к другим словообразовательным типам, например: гро'зненский (Грозный), городи'щенский (Городище), заре'ченский (Заречье), фру'нзенский (Фрунзе), коло'менский (Коломна), песо'ченский (Песочня), горше'ченский (Горшечное). (В последних трех примерах прилагательные содержат в своем составе беглое е и суффикс -ск-.)

   ```
    Нищенский от нищий. Непонятно. Спорить с автором не хочется,
     написано именно от основ.
   ```

Не вижу здесь слов "от основы". Нищенский - от нищий. Имеется в виду "от слова нищий",т.е. не на -ин, -и(ы),-а(я),поэтому -енск, а не -инск.

А вообще пишется -енск  в прилагательных, образованных:

а) от географических названий на -ный, -ное , напр.: Грозный – грозненский, Изобильный – изобильненский, Мирный – мирненский, Отрадное – отрадненский, Свободный – свободненский, Спорное – спорненский;

б) от географических названий на -но , напр.: Гродно – гродненский, Молодечно – молодечненский, Ровно – ровненский, Тосно – тосненский;

в) от слов с основой на -ищ  (кроме слов на -ищи ), напр.: нищий – нищенский, кладбище – кладбищенский, Городище (город, поселок) – городищенский, Займище (поселок) – займищенский.

Иногда говорят "образовано от слова на -и (Мытищи), а не от основы слова на -и". Скорее всего, там так.Вы действительно не так поняли.

По Вашей ссылке тоже ошибок не нашла, где Вы сказали 2 правило неверное, но кое-что не совсем научно. Попробуйте по этому сайту заниматься:https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%

Драбкину не видела, мы по Сениной занимаемся, по Цыбулько, по Васильевым, проблем нет.